# How To Add MySQL Interval At Once?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please have a look into the following query:

```
UPDATE `un_test` 
SET `test_time` = DATE_ADD(`test_time`, INTERVAL 'test_minute' MINUTE) 
WHERE deliver_at_user < NOW();
```

It will add 5 minutes if the db time is less then current time.

Now if the `test_time` time is more than 5 minutes old, after executing this query, `test_time` doesn't meet the criteria still.

What I am looking for, if there is any shortcut way to add the multiple of `test_minute` to `test_time` field at once so that it meet the criteria/`test_time` updated with next possible valid time?

I am looking for SQL query level solution and don't want to write PHP script for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to update test_time to be greater than sysdate?

Comment: yes, exactly. but the added interval must need to be multiple of 'test_minute'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update un_test
set test_time = date_add(test_time, interval 
    cast(ceiling(timestampdiff(minute, test_time, now())/test_minute) 
    * test_minute as int) minute)
where deliver_at_user < now()
```

This should work, more or less. :D

The logic that follows is this

1. Calculate how much test_time is lagging, and subsequently, how many rounds of test_minute have to be added to it.
2. Round the decimal up. This is the most important bit because this will make sure that the resulting test_time is more than sysdate
3. Multiply the result with test_minute and add it to test_minute.

Comment: great, thanks. This is something I have ended up myself just a while ago. However, I didn't use 'cast' function and seems working without it. Is it necessary for some reason/case?

Comment: The `expr` in date_add is always cast to a string. So, if you are using decimal values, you have to be careful. However, in this case, it is not required since you are working with pure int values.